# Monitor webserver accessibility inconsistencies

Tags: java, logging, server

I have written a simple application to monitor whether a couple of Java EE 6 web applications deployed to Glassfish 3.1.2.2 are accessible. My intent is to demonstrate to our operations team that the applications are intermittently inaccessible.

```
package monitoring;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class Monitoring {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MonitoringLogger");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        configureLogger();
        URL[] urls = {
            new URL("http://alpha:11480/AlphaApplication-war/"), 
            new URL("http://beta:11680/BetaApplication-war/")
        };
        while (true) {
            for (URL url : urls) {
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                    while (reader.ready()) {
                        logger.info(reader.readLine());
                    }
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException exception) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Read timed out to {0}", url);
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5));
        }
    }

    private static void configureLogger() throws IOException {
        FileHandler fh;
        fh = new FileHandler("logfile.log");
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
        logger.info("Logger initialized");
    }
}
```

When the connection is successful, the reply is logged. When the connection times-out, the timeout is logged.

A Windows batch file runs this application on start-up:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Me\Monitoring\dist\Monitoring.jar"
pause
```

I'm satisfied with the behaviour of this application, but I'm using unfamiliar APIs to accomplish an unfamiliar task, so I'm looking for broad advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept in your code is fundamentally good, but there are a few things I would recommend you change.

### Static initializers

First up, I like static initializer functions when the static component is non-trivial. So, for example, this code:

> ```
> private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MonitoringLogger");
>
> public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException {
>     configureLogger();
>     ......
> }
>
> private static void configureLogger() throws IOException {
>     FileHandler fh;
>     fh = new FileHandler("logfile.log");
>     logger.addHandler(fh);
>     SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
>     fh.setFormatter(formatter);
>     logger.info("Logger initialized");
> }
> ```

I would replace with:

```
private static final Logger logger = configureLogger();

private static Logger configureLogger() {

    try {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MonitoringLogger");
        FileHandler fh;
        fh = new FileHandler("logfile.log");
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
        logger.info("Logger initialized");
        return logger;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not get logger up.", ioe);
    }
}
```

That's a 'trivial' change, but it puts the initialization sequence of the code in to a much more structured system.

### What to log.

You don't really want to be logging what the sites are showing, you want to be logging their response times. I suggest pulling different metrics than the ones you are getting..... How long it took for the repsonse to come, and whether it was successful, or not. A log that looks like:

> ```
> 2015-07-22 12:23:34 [INFO] 3ms response from http://alpha:11480/AlphaApplication-war/
> 2015-07-22 12:26:12 [INFO] 3984ms response from http://alpha:11480/AlphaApplication-war/
> 2015-07-22 12:29:49 [ERROR] 5000ms TIME OUT FROM http://alpha:11480/AlphaApplication-war/
> ```

That would be much easier to process.

To do that, you will want to measure the actual times, not the responses... and you will pick up slow-to-respond servers too (perhaps a big garbage collection, over-congested network handler, or something).

So, create a function that has a response, which should be an Object:

```
private static final class ServerStat {
    private final boolean success;
    private final long milliseconds;

    ServerStat(boolean success, long milliseconds) {
        .....
    }
}
```

and then a function that tests an HTTP URL:

```
public static ServerStat pingServer(URL host) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    boolean ok = false;
    try {

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        try (InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream()) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while (stream.read(buffer) >= 0) {
                // throw the data away
            }
        }
        // no exceptions
        ok = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // swallow any exception
    }
    return new ServerStat(ok, System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
}
```

Now, you have a function which times how long it takes to get a complete response (or fail) from a server.

Now, instead of having an infinite while-loop, have a non-daemon scheduled thread executor instead. Something like:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> pingServerList(totest), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

That runs a function every 5 seconds.

I put it all together like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class PingServer {

    private static final class ServerStat {
        private final boolean success;
        private final long milliseconds;
        private final String message;
    
        ServerStat(boolean success, long milliseconds, String message) {
            this.success = success;
            this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
            this.message = message;
        }
    }

    public static ServerStat pingServer(URL url) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        boolean ok = false;
        String message = "OK";
        try {

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(3000);
            try (InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream()) {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                while (stream.read(buffer) >= 0) {
                    // throw the data away
                }
            }
            // no exceptions
            ok = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage();
        }
        return new ServerStat(ok, System.currentTimeMillis() - start, message);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<URL> totest = Arrays.asList(new URL("http://localhost:3000"));
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> pingServerList(totest), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        
    }

    private static void pingServerList(List<URL> totest) {
        for(URL url : totest) {
            ServerStat ss = pingServer(url);
            System.out.printf("%tc [%s] %dms %s %s\n", System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    ss.success ? "INFO" : "ERROR", 
                    ss.milliseconds, url.toString(), ss.message);
        }
    }

}
```

and when I run it on my machine, with a test server running (then not running), I get the output:

> ```
> Wed Jul 22 16:20:51 EDT 2015 [ERROR] 22ms http://localhost:3000 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> Wed Jul 22 16:20:56 EDT 2015 [ERROR] 1ms http://localhost:3000 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> Wed Jul 22 16:21:01 EDT 2015 [ERROR] 2ms http://localhost:3000 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> Wed Jul 22 16:21:06 EDT 2015 [INFO] 21ms http://localhost:3000 OK
> Wed Jul 22 16:21:11 EDT 2015 [INFO] 8ms http://localhost:3000 OK
> Wed Jul 22 16:21:16 EDT 2015 [INFO] 5ms http://localhost:3000 OK
> Wed Jul 22 16:21:21 EDT 2015 [INFO] 4ms http://localhost:3000 OK
> Wed Jul 22 16:21:26 EDT 2015 [ERROR] 4ms http://localhost:3000 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> ```

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you. This is exactly what I was hoping for: a mixture of API, code structure, and problem solving advice.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto [@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97738/27975)'s excellent answer, may I suggest that you should/can also take in the list of URLs from `args`?

```
List<URL> urls = Stream.of(args).map(URL::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will mean that adding or changing URLs doesn't require you to rebuild your Java jar file every time. :)